# Why I can't execute Java method in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, java, spring

Please have a look at the JavaScript code below:

```js
const locations = /*[[${locations}]]*/ null;
locations.forEach(location => {
    location.description = 44;
    location.lnglat = 127;

    location.fun(); // error
});
```

`description` and `lnglat` are variables from Java list of objects of class 'Location'; `fun` is a function from this class.

There is no problem assigning values to variables, but I can't call the function `fun`. Unfortunately, I don't know what the reason is and how can I fix it.
In Java, I use Spring Boot and method `addAttribute`:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String homePage(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("locations", locations());
     return "home";
}
```

Comment: so, where is supposed the Java runtime to be ? in the browser ?

Comment: If you somehow convert Java objects to JSON and then load them into JavaScript (I don't know how else you would be doing this), you would be able to get the attributes that are JSON compatible (basically just strings, booleans, and numbers). Functions are not part of JSON. There is no way to represent a Java function as a generic enough object that JavaScript can also understand it. Java and JavaScript are 2 totally separate languages, so there isn't really a way to just convert functions between them.

Comment: @MisterJojo, I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but I think so, in the browser.

Comment: I don't believe there can be a browser with a built-in JVM

Comment: @nullromo, thank you! Thanks to this, I know what strategy I can choose. I won't continue to get stuck in calling functions from two different programming languages.

Comment: @MisterJojo, so why can I use a variables (from Java) in JavaScript code?

Comment: you can get data from a java server, you can't execute java code on a browser

Comment: @MisterJojo, suppose the function is executing on java server. So why can't I call it?

Comment: if you want to execute anything on a server from a client browser anywhere in the world, you need to use AJAX

Comment: AJAX! OK, I read a bit about its use. However, I think that I will use JSON here (to initialize variables, instead of using functions for that).
Thanks for the answers.